# fastapi body not working properly with Body and Depends for singular values in Body

Tags: python, fastapi

I have this small fastapi application

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Query
from fastapi import Path

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(
        id: str = Path(...),
        q: str = Query(...),
        b: str = Body(...)
):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it works as expected.

---

But I now make some changes as below

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Body, Query
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Input(BaseModel):
    id: str = Path(...)
    q: str = Query(...)
    b: str = Body(...)


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: Input = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect b to be shown as Body in the docs but it is being interpreted as a query string.

What is wrong?

Comment: you probably need to add `b: str = Field(Body(...))` and so on for the others in the pydantic model you have

Answer (score 0):

A few things to be done to make the endpoint work

1. Update `b: str = Body(...)` to `b: str = Field(Body(...))`.
2. `get` request cannot have request body as input and will return an error. Use `post` request instead.
   [image]
3. The name of the `path` parameter should be consistent with the path `/test/{test_id}`, hence it should be `test_id` instead of `id`. Or else it will return a `422 Error: Unprocessable Entity`.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Body, Query
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()


class Input(BaseModel):
    test_id: str = Path(...)
    q: str = Query(...)
    b: str = Field(Body(...))


@app.post("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: Input = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```